# What should come as object ? I or me?

Tags: word-usage

I am smarter than Jake, but he's richer than (me or I).

What should come as the object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an *object* of the *preposition* than, it's **me**.

> I am smarter than Jake, but he's richer than me.

*Than* can also function as a *conjunction*:

> I am smarter than Jake, but he's richer than *I am*.

*Am* is often omitted but that is considered acceptable:

https://www.washingtonpost.com/news/volokh-conspiracy/wp/2014/01/24/is-it-now-acceptable-grammar-to-say-is-a-much-better-advocate-than-me-and-95-of-my-colleagues/?noredirect=on&utm_term=.43f144bedfcb

Comment: You start off by stating that the answer is **me**, then demonstrate it can also be **I**. It sounds like you're contradicting yourself, even though you aren't. I would suggest adding a sentence at the start that says it can be either, depending on how you interpret it.

Comment: The question was about the _object_ (of the _preposition_ than), so I started with that option.

Comment: The whole point is that than me versus than I (am) is a question of colloquial/spoken English versus more formal spoken English.  Also, there is no object of a preposition anywhere in the sentence.

Comment: The pronoun _me_ is the object of the preposition _than_ in the first sentence, at least by this concept: https://www.thoughtco.com/object-of-a-preposition-op-1691447